# How do you add a Voting Field to a Task List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I am creating a task list that management will be voting on to determine priority.

I was looking for a solution to add a voting field that would show when not in edit mode.  And later a field that would calculate the votes into a percentage (the easy part, I think). Any solution would work, even third party recommended apps.

Comment: Have a look at the ratings settings that all lists have. Using the star format(instead of likes) it will automatically calculate the average score.

Comment: I had never thought of using the rating setting.  Thanks.  I think that may work for our needs.  Just need to figure out how to reset the data so the same list can be reused when new priorities are created/eliminated.

Comment: If the mechanics are going ot be the same just delete the old items/hide the old items by using views